# ToString() creates an object on the heap?

Tags: c#, heap-memory, cil

num.ToString() Will create an object on the heap during the execution of WriteLine()?

```
int num = 83424;
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString());
```

Comment: Either way: I'm curious what you intend to do with this information once you get it.

Comment: That's a strong implementation detail.  I can easily envision a [profile guided just-in-time compiler](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/conversation-about-pgo/) that will intern that string.  Other than that, objects who's runtime size are unpredictable fit only on a heap.  Never makes it out of gen#0, nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Wyck Reading a CLR book through C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost certainly, yes. There may be some behind-the-scenes tricks to avoid allocations for some small integers, zero, etc (a quick test in .NET 6 and .NET 7 suggests this is the case for 0-9 inclusive).

If that isn't desirable, there are ways of avoiding it - for example `Utf8Formatter` has methods to write primitives to a span, typically some reusable buffer memory - but this has a different API and usage than `ToString()`.

Comment: Learn something new every day! Just curious is this because a string is really a pointer so the contents of the string would go on the heap but the pointer is still returned via the stack?

Comment: @JustAnswertheQuestion no, the string isn't a pointer; a string is a string, and a reference is a reference; the string goes on the heap, always; the reference to the string is returned via the stack, the same as any return value; nothing unusual or unexpected happens in this case

Comment: Well just that we think of strings as value types but they're not in this case. Also pointer = reference. I come from C/C++ originally so old habits die hard. :)

Comment: @MarcGravell how can this be checked? How did you check it  (a quick test in .NET 6 and .NET 7 suggests this is the case for 0-9 inclusive)?

Comment: @Naydachy, dotnet is open source, so it can be inspected. As for now, depending on runtime, cache can vary between 10 and 300: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5af47bb4da45f7255ed78dc22fff45fda509ff42/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Number.Formatting.cs#L278

Comment: @Naydachy like this: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7AHwDNoACACgEs8NTLSBeUuARgAYBuO0gHlIFY2nOgGoRASgCwAKADeM0orpEKAJRhEYsPGBgBRAI44AhgBsAzlQB0AFQgBlDFGoBzcuLR1bDp6/fipaSVSeSDgpQABFisogE5yABIAIllKAF9SYwAHLJhjKHNSDAhSPAhaM1MIMGMMGFJcqDga01Mk8Q4FJTSZNKA= (note this will change in .NET 8)

Comment: @JL0PD interestingly, we don't seem to be hitting that 300 case yet: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7AHwDNoACACgEs8NTLSBeUuARgAYBuO0gHlIFY2nOgGoRASgCwAKADeM0orpEKAJRhEYsPGBgBRAI44AhgBsAzlQB0AFQgBlDFGoBzcuLR1bDp6/fipaSVSeSDgpQABFisogE5yABIAIllKAF9SYwAHLJhjKHNSDAhSPAhaM1MIMGMMGFJcqDga01Mk8Q4FJTSZNKA= - that changed Dec 2 2022, so maybe in .NET 8

Comment: @MarcGravell , That is, for the numbers (0-9) an object is created in a heap, but for all remaining ones there is not?

Comment: @Naydachy for the integers [0-9] (and [0-300) in net8+), an object is created on the heap *the first time it is needed for that integer* (i.e. the same `string` object will be returned for all future calls to `ToString()` for an integer with the same value); for all the other integers: an object is created on the heap **every time** you call `.ToString()`